# how to remove conda envs

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I have created two environments(`env1` and `env2`) in the following path:

```
Users/user/conda/envs
```

I want to remove `env1` and have tried every combination of the following commands but it is not removing:

```
conda remove --name env1
conda remove --name conda/envs/env1
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 34):

You can use the following command lines in terminal (permissions may be required):

```
conda env remove --name myenv
```

alternatively:

```
conda remove --name myenv --all
```

You can do `conda info --envs` to verify the action was successful.

More info [here](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#removing-an-environment).

Comment: thanks! I tried both but they don't work; it returns:
conda-env: error: unrecognized arguments: --env1

Comment: maybe it is a typo in th ename of your env? if you type `conda env list` in terminal, you will see a list of the various environments.

Comment: I should have mentioned that i created those envs through miniconda.  In my directory I have `Users/user/conda/envs/env1`
if I activate the envs:
`$ source activate conda/envs`
and then `conda env list` which return :
`py37                     /anaconda/envs/py37
root                     /anaconda`

Comment: You can just remove the environment directory.

Answer (score 2):

Some misunderstanding here - I think you were trying to replace `--name` with your environment name which will not work, while you have to replace `myenv` with your environment name.

Comment: THIS was my problem!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the [documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#removing-an-environment) is not that clear. If the environment has not any package installed the command `conda remove --name myenv --all` won't work. In that case it's necessary to use `conda env remove --name myenv`. The issue is commented on [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8351)

Answer (score 1):

I tried a lot of things too and then found "conda-env" was the key.

```
conda-env remove -n myenv
```

Answer (score 0):

**For those who can't find a name or have the same name env for every environment they've created then you need to execute this command to remove the conda env from specific directory**

> conda remove --prefix /path/to/conda-env/ --all

Answer (score 0):

If `conda remove --name ENV_NAME -all`, did not delete the environment and its associated folders, one can start the anaconda navigator GUI:

- Search for navigator on Windows and start the app.
- For Linux, you may execute the command anaconda-navigator and the GUI should start.

From the GUI, go and select the environment, once it loads, hit on delete.